# ejabberd localhost the connection was interrupted but logs say connection was accepted

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm completely new to ejabber.
I have installed ejabber on debian (on virtual machine) but when I tried to check it with localhost (http://localhost:5280/admin) mozilla responded with the announcement "the connection was interrupted". I checked logs of ejabber and it had multiple lines of accepting connection on port 5280.

```
2018-06-02 14:27:50.526 [info] <0.491.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.12507>) Accepted connection ::1:32948 -> ::1:5280
2018-06-02 14:27:50.534 [info] <0.635.0>@ejabberd_http:init:163 started: {fast_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.12507>,#Port<0.12508>}}
```

What is the reason of it and how could I get past this issue?